# Get modified date of blobs in Synapse Notebooks

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-synapse, azure-notebooks

I have, in one Storage Account, a container with folders and subfolders. In one of them, like `container foo` and `path fee/fii`, i have a large amount of files. I want to get the last modified date of every blob in my Notebook. I cannot solve this problem, I have searched but nothing likely appears. How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Follow these steps:**

Mount your [storage account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/synapse-file-mount-api#How-to-mount-Gen2/blob-Storage) in azure synapse

```
mssparkutils.fs.mount( 
    "wasbs://<container_name>@<storage_account_name>.blob.core.windows.net/folder/", 
    "/<mount_name>/", 
    {"linkedService":"Linked_service_name"} 
)
```

**Sample code:**

```
import os
from datetime import datetime
path = '/'
fpaths = [path+"/"+fd for fd in os.listdir(path)]
print(" file_path " + " create_date " + " modified_date ")
for fpath in fpaths:
statinfo = os.stat(fpath)
create_date = datetime.fromtimestamp(statinfo.st_ctime)
modified_date = datetime.fromtimestamp(statinfo.st_mtime)
print(fpath, create_date, modified_date)
```

**Output:**

[image: Ref1]

For more details refer this [Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/506733/datalake-get-last-file-modified-date-in-synapse-no.html) by SaurabhSharma-msft

Comment: For me, this does not give me information about the files in the specific mounted path. Should the ```path``` really be ```/```?